# DayClick event alert in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When a user clicks on a day slot in a month view in the Fullcalendar dayClick event I'd like to have a "past date" alert if a date and a time of the day is less than the date and time is now. The fullcalendar is integrated in a ASP.NET MVC app.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        var today=new Date();
        if(today.getHours() != 0 && today.getMinutes() != 0 && 
           today.getSeconds() != 0 && today.getMilliseconds() != 0){
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        }
        if (date<today){
            alert("Past Date");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, thank you! It works, the only question is, why when I click on the today's date (October 10) it considers the today's date as a past date. In your "if" statement "date<today", not "<=". Could you please advise?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added a line like, today.setHours(0,0,0,0); before the comparison. The issue is that the date is today's date at 0:00:00:00 while today is today's date at the current time. If you add that line everything should be fixed.

Comment: Is it possible to use the same function, 'dayClick' to issue a "past time" alert for today, but only if the time of today is less than the current time is now. Otherwise, if the current time is '>=' "date.time.now" there is no alert? I tried to use "var now = new Date();", but it works same way as "today" in your example. Sorry to bother you. Please advise, if possible. Thank you!

Comment: I have added an edit to the code that will now take into account if a user selects a time in an agenda view that is before the current time. When you can do so, an up vote would be appreciated.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! When I asked you that question I realized that it was irrelevant. Actually my problem is with the Form where I have a Date text field and two dropdown fields, Start Time and End Time. When a user selects time from a dropdown StartTime field I'd like to have a "past time" alert if a time of the day is less than the time is now.

I want to disable the past times for selection. So I can select only times starting from current time. How is it possible? How can I filter the times and specify a condition?

I'll appreciate your advise!

Comment: You could have a javascript function that filters the options based on the current time based on the current date. If you want to make another question and post some more code with your HTML markup I could give you some more specific advise.

Comment: Yes, please, i'll appreciate your advise!
Here is the HTML code:

Comment: <label for="Date">Date</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Date", Model.Request.Date, new { @class="required" })%>
               <label for="Start">StartTime</label>
            <%=Html.DropDownList("Start",Model.Request.Start Times, { new{@class="required"})%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Start", "*")%>
                <label for="End">EndTime</label>
                <%=Html.DropDownList("End",Model.Request.EndTimes, { new{@class="required"})%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("End", "*")%>

Comment: I'm having a really difficult time reading your code in the comments. This is actually a different question, so if you want to make a new stack overflow question I'll be able to read the code better and I'd be more then happy to provide an answer.

Comment: Hi Jeff! I posted this question at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879591/how-to-compare-start-and-end-time-selections-of-the-same-day
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) { 
                var myDate = new Date();

                if (date < myDate) {
                    //TRUE Clicked date smaller than today + daysToadd
                    alert("Past Date");
                }
                else
                {
                    //FLASE Clicked date larger than today + daysToadd
                    alert("Good choice");   
                 }   
            }
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SteveButabi/RAmYV/